# Matching widths of two different functions

Tags: integration, gaussian-integral, rectangles

Say I have a rectangular function as follows $$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
1  & \text{$|x|$$\leq$$x_0$} \\[2ex]
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

I want to match its width (which in this case is $2x_0$) to that of a Gaussian defined as, say, $exp(-2x^2/\sigma^2)$ (i.e., $\sigma^2$. I want to write some relation between $\sigma^2$ and $x_0$). Is there a standard or conventional way to do this?

Comment: A Gaussian is nonzero everywhere, so it has no width in the sense $f(x)$ has. On the other hand, the width of the bell curve is defined by the value of $\sigma$. For example, $99.5$% of its surface area is under the curve on the interval $[-2\sigma , 2\sigma]$.

Comment: There's no doubt that you're right. I'll try to explain myself a little better: In some calculations I made I assumed $f(x)$ to be a Gaussian function. Now, in some scenarios this assumption doesn't hold and $f(x)$ could take the form of a rectangular function. I was looking for a way to match the $\sigma^2$ from the Gaussian I assumed to that of a width of a rectangular function. I realize that widths here mean something different for each function and the result wouldn't really be accurate.

Comment: anyone with any ideas?